# Magento create custom career form and call from CMS page

Tags: javascript, php, forms, magento

How to create custom form and call from it career cms page? Currently I am creating a cms career page and a file in core template and calling it with

```
{{block type="core/template" name="careerform" template="careerform/career_form.phtml"}}
```

this is calling fine and my `career_form` is

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" name="contact_form">
            <div class="fieldset">
                <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
                <ul class="form-list">
                    <li class="fields">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="field">
                         <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Phone') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Phone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
                            </div>
                       </div>
                        <div class="field">
                          <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                          <div class="input-box">
                            <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                          </div>
                       </div>
                   </li>

            <li class="wide">
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your Details') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your Details') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="subject"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Which store?') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="input-box"><input name="subject" id="subject" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Which store? ') ?>" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
    //]]>
</script>
```

Problem is this is redirect to contact us page
I want to ask,has anyone idea that how to achieve career form?
Thanks

Comment: The form you are providing, is the contact form, see the fields. so it is displaying contact form.

Comment: what is the way to achieve this?How to  create custom form?

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly assigned the file which displays the carrer form i.e. **career_form.phtml**. Now you just need to create simple HTML form in this file with the fields that are requited for you.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl(''); ?>" id="carrer" method="post" name="carrer_form">

// Add the fields according to your requirement.

</form>
```

Above is the form now after creating the form you need to change the action of the form. In the previous form i.e. contact form the action of the form points to

`<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>`

This gives the url

> www.your_domain.com/index.php/contacts/index/post

This is the location of the module/controller/action where you process the information sent from the form.This you should change according to your controllers action.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestion,we have done this with create a module and controller function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally created a module and create a controller action and get here all post value from phtml file,use magento mail function for sending mail.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't comment in the answer section.If this works then its great.If my answer was helpful than don't forget to accept and vote up because this will help other to tackle similar problem as yours. Cheers!!